# SQLite syntax error on drop table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, syntax-error

i am creating a SQLite database but im having syntax error on the following statement "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Case;". The 'Case' table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE Case(
idCase INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
dentistname TEXT,
patientname TEXT,
description TEXT NOT NULL,
closed INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
CHECK(closed BETWEEN 0 AND 1)
);
```

Comment: don't use sql keywords for table or column names, it will give you headaches and bugs.

Comment: You need to use a quoted identifier:  `"Case"`  for details see the manual: https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html But I agree with Tristan: don't use keywords as identifiers.

Comment: Thanks to all. The issue is now solved, i changed the name of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the Table name in brackets like so

```
    Drop Table If Exists [dbo].[Case]
```

I would also suggest avoiding sql keywords to name columns or tables, or anything else as you will have to use the brackets to make sure that SQL knows that its a user defined name rather than a keyword.

Comment: SQLite also supports the SQL standard way of quoting keywords using double quotes `"` - which is preferred over the non-standard Microsoft style.